# Android AndEngine line doesn't collide with others

Tags: android, andengine

My line body:

```
lineFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(
                            1,     // density
                            0.75f,  // elasticity
                            0.5f, // friction
                            false); // isSensor

                    lBody = PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(physicsWorld, line5, lineFixtureDef);
                    lBody.setUserData("lineBody");
```

My contact listener :

```
                @Override
                public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
                    final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

                    if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("pSprite") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("eSprite"))
                    {
                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN PLAYER AND MONSTER!");
                        lost();
                    } else if(x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("eSprite") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("lineBody"))
                    {
                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN LINE AND MONSTER!");
                        mScore += 1;
                        mText.setText(" "+mScore+"");
                    }
                }
```

Now when the eSprite with pSprite collide, the lost(); works .. but if line and eSprite collide nothing happens ..

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("pSprite") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("eSprite"))
                    {
                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN PLAYER AND MONSTER!");
                        lost();
                    } else if(x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("eSprite") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("pSprite"))
                    {
                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN PLAYER AND MONSTER!");
                        mScore += 1;
                        mText.setText(" "+mScore+"");
                    }

 if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("lineBody") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("eSprite"))
                    {
                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN LINE AND MONSTER!");
                        lost();
                    } else if(x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("eSprite") && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("lineBody"))
                    {
                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN LINE AND MONSTER!");
                        mScore += 1;
                        mText.setText(" "+mScore+"");
                    }
```

Comment: May be in your case x1 being  line and x2 is eSprite

Comment: try with creating rectangle

Comment: can you help me with that ? I need a line in the scene's center, how can this be achieved with rectangles

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java check this link. it may help you

Comment: I looked at it, how can a create a line at the scene's center from the top to the bottom using a rectangle ?